# What is a "mechanical pad"?

Tags: pcb, soldering, breakout, fpc

I've bought an FPC breakout stick from: [Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1325). In its datasheet, it mentions a "mechanical pad", which is the exposed copper bar near the connection pads. What does it do, and can I utilize it while soldering the FPC cable onto the board?

Here is the picture of the stick:
[image]

Comment: Did you  look at the example pics on the Adafruit site? Two of them clearly show  connectors with tabs on their sides being soldered to this strip.  If your intended device does not have such a tab, then I suppose you cannot use the strip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "mechanical pad" is where you attach the housing of the flex connector you are using.

The adapter board is **not** intended to have the flex soldered to it.

The idea is that you solder a proper connector for your flex on the adapter board.  Then, you solder connections to the provided through hole points.

This lets you connect your flex to a circuit, then unplug and reconnect it without destroying your flex.